# Retroactively filter Google Analytics by subdirectory

Tags: google-analytics

I'm aware that I can add a filter to Google Analytics to see results for a particular subdirectory, but I'm not clear on whether or not it's possible to use that filter retroactively. In this particular case, I'd like to see the geographical data for visitors to a particular subdirectory only, for data that has already been collected over the past few years. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related.

Comment: Apologies, I had seen other analytics questions here so I thought this was all right here as well.

Comment: Stack overflow is a codeing forum Google analytics website is a web application i try to close as many as i can but its hard to keep up with them.  try asking here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you! Will do